# Map offsite with matplotlib(using geopandas and cartopy)

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy, geopandas

I have created a map like this: [image: map]

The problem with it is that on the right side of the map is always a little bit offsite. I have set the bounds to:

```
ax.set_xlim(-215800,
            1000000)
ax.set_ylim(3402659,
            4879248)
```

No matter how I increase the xlim, or set margin the right side is still outside the bounds of the canvas. Can somebody help?

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from osgeo import ogr

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import rasterio
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

import geopandas
from geopandas import *

from matplotlib import colors



MediumApple='#55FF00'
Cantaloupe='#FFA77F'
Marsred='#FF0000'
crs = ccrs.UTM(zone=10)
ax = plt.axes(projection=crs)
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

for county in CAcountylist:
    with rasterio.drivers():
        with rasterio.open(r"CA\%s \%s.tif"%(county,county),"r") as src:
            meta = src.meta
            im=src.read().astype('f')
            im=np.transpose(im,[1,2,0])
            print im.shape
            print im.min(),im.max()
            im[im==0]=np.nan
            im=im.squeeze()
            xmin = src.transform[0]
            xmax = src.transform[0] + src.transform[1]*src.width
            print src.width,src.height
            ymin = src.transform[3] + src.transform[5]*src.height
            ymax = src.transform[3]
            colors=[MediumApple,Cantaloupe,Marsred]
             cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap([MediumApple,Cantaloupe,Marsred])
            bounds_color=[1,1,2,2,3,3]

            norm=mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds_color,cmap.N)
            print xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax
            ax.imshow(im, origin='upper', extent=[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax], transform=crs, interpolation='nearest',cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
df=GeoDataFrame.from_file(r"\CACounty.shp")
df=df.to_crs(epsg=26910)
df.plot(axes=ax,alpha=0)
bounds = df.geometry.bounds
ax.set_xlim(-215800,
            1000000)
ax.set_ylim(3402659,
            4879248)
low_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='#55FF00', label='Low')
Moderate_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='#FFA77F', label='Moderate')
High_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='#FF0000', label='High')

plt.legend(handles=[low_patch,Moderate_patch,High_patch],loc=3)         


plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi alice, can you point to me a link for this CAcounty.shp file? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is solved by reprojected everything in wgs  1984

Comment: @alice If you found a solution to your own question, you may provide an answer yourself and accept it, such that the question does not stay unsolved forever.

Comment: can you add your own answer please, also what is your takeaway of using geopandas, rasterio and cartopy combined?